# Strange CDATA behavior in XHTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xhtml

i'm using blogger and i want to make my own template from scratch so i began to understand the very basic structure of how things are.
In my journey through this i encounter the CDATA thing
And i wanted to test this code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <b:skin>
      <![CDATA[ ]]>
    </b:skin>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b:section id='post'/>
    <script>
      if(true&&true)
        alert("hello");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It gives me an error and i know that the "&" should be "&" instead because it's xhtml so i add the cdata my code will become like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <b:skin>
      <![CDATA[ ]]>
    </b:skin>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b:section id='post'/>
    <script>
      <![CDATA[
      if(true&&true)
        alert("hello");
      ]]>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now that i test it the alert message wouldn't show up so i put // before the opening and closing CDATA tag and it works.
I want to understand why the reason it works with // and not without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogger parses the XML templates as XML, so they need to be valid XML to work with Blogger's backend.

However, when Blogger serves the resulting page to the browser it says that the Content-Type is `text/html; charset=UTF-8` (which is wrong, because it is XHTML (but see below)).

HTML and XHTML are different languages so when the browser parses the XHTML as HTML it doesn't do anything special with `<![CDATA[` and just passes it to the JavaScript engine.

`<![CDATA[` isn't valid JavaScript, so this throws an exception.

By prefixing it `//`, you change the invalid JavaScript into a valid JavaScript line comment.

---

*aside*: XHTML and HTML are similar enough that you can get away with pretending your XHTML is HTML if you [follow the compatibility guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/).

Comment: And the reason why when Blogger serves the resulting page to the browser it says that the Content-Type is text/html; charset=UTF-8 which is wrong?